# Visibility of a method in C#

Tags: c#, static-methods

In C# 6.0 there is a new feature `using static` which allows to use code like this

```
using static Query.QueryBuilder;

static void BuildQuery()
{
    var newQuery = Where(Eq("Value1","Value2"))
}
```

where the methods to build a query are static methods in a class `QueryBuilder`

```
namespace Query
{
    public static QueryBuilder
    {
       public static string Where(Object obj);
       public static string Eq(Object obj);

    } 
}
```

This allows to drop specifying static class name `QueryBuilder` to call static methods from this class.

Is it possible to do something similar in C# 3.0? There is a way to do it with aliasing, but it still would be needed to use some kind of shortened prefix to call methods.

Comment: Personally I'd say don't use this feature at all. You avoid typing a few characters but the code will be a lot less clear. I know this is probably not the popular opinion but there's value to be able to look at code in Notepad (without tooltip help).

Comment: *In C# 6.0 there is a **new** feature*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, static usings are brand new to C# 6, and there is no way to get the same behavior (not needing the class name).

As you have mentioned, there are ways to get close, but nothing exactly the same in earlier versions.